# How to change default location of bookmarks in Firefox 4?

Tags: bookmarks, firefox

I just upgraded to Firefox 4.0 and I am wondering how do I make it so when I click the "Star" to bookmark that the bookmark ends up in the "Bookmarks" Menu instead of "Unsorted Bookmarks".

I don't use the bookmark menu but that is where all my other bookmarks are so I rather keep them in the same place.

Comment: A discussion [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/797132).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **double-click the star** when adding it to your favorites, it will bring up a dialog box with more options, *including which folder you would like the bookmark to be added to*, like so:

[image]

The other option is to use an addon:

[**Add Bookmark Here 2**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/) addon from Mozilla Addons.

> Main Features
>
> - Expand all fields in Bookmark Dialog.
> - Customize the position of "Add Bookmark Here" & "Open All Tabs".
> - Remember the last selected folder when you bookmark a page.
> - Insert bookmarks from the top of Menu.
> - Add a bookmark without showing the Bookmark Dialog.
> - Single-click the Star to show the Bookmark Dialog.
> - Resize the Folder-Tree, Tags-List, Description-Field in Bookmark Dialog.
> - Customize the location of Unsorted Bookmarks Folder.
> - Show the Tags in Inline.
> - Middle-click Bookmark Star can Open Library to Organize Bookmarks.
> - Middle-click on a folder to add bookmark into the folder.

Note: I am not affiliated with this product/software in any way, shape. or form.

[Image Source here.](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/07/15/how-to-bookmark-a-web-page-into-firefox-3-bookmarks-folder-when-clicking-on-star-on-location-bar/).